# text color not working in safari, I don't have macOS to fix it can you help me

Tags: html, css

I have a btn-group on this [page](https://beta.tt.social/physical-products), in the `My Physical Product` section's cards, the text in the button must be gradient *but if it's impossible, normal text color is ok*. It's not visible, check it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaGXc.png).
it must be like this on [light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxFqy.png) and [dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrHUl.png) *all browsers' view* 
It works on every device/browser, except iPhone-safari and iPad-safari, I couldn't fix this because I don't have **macOS**.

## **Notes:**

- the body tag has the browser name (the browser that you've opened the
  site in)
- I didn't publish the code here because I can't check if it
  not working on safari, and I can't publish the whole site here
- there's a dark layout on the website, please fix the text in both the dark and light layouts

you can see how I want the text to be like from any other browser/device from [here](https://beta.tt.social/physical-products), just for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a btn-group on this page, in the My Physical Product section's cards, the text in the button must be gradient but if it's impossible, normal text color is ok. It's not visible, check it here.
it must be like this on light and dark all browsers' view
It works on every device/browser, except iPhone-safari and iPad-safari, I couldn't fix this because I don't have macOS.